# Proper export from txt to html in Powershell

Tags: html, powershell, type-conversion

I have a script, which stores output in txt and I need to convert this output into html.

The format of txt file is following:

```
This file is generated  for commits from: 2018-07-15 to: 2018-07-21 for branch:  repositories contains: mineq


=============somerepo=============


Branch is development
1234567 Merge pull request #1227 from qp-10421_service_version_information
1234567 Merge branch 'development' into qp-10421_service_version_information
1234567 merged with development
1234567 QP-2071: update packages




=============Someotherrepo=============


Branch is development




=============MineqConfigApi=============


Branch is development
1234567 QP-10881 Remove WindowsVpnSettings service
1234567 Merge pull request #9 from quarti/QP-10881
1234567 QP-10881 Set SshClient ConnectionTimeout 10 minutes and Change sql query to skip Deleted Assets
```

To send this text into html, I use following code:

```
$SourceFile = "$env:WORKSPACE\commits.txt"
$TargetFile = "$env:WORKSPACE\commits.html"
$TextData = Get-Content $SourceFile
$LineData = $TextData -join ''
New-Object psobject -Property @{Text = $LineData} | ConvertTo-HTML | Out-File $TargetFile
```

But the output is following -

How to rework script, to receive exact output, with linebreaks, as in txt file?

Comment: is it just line breaks you are missing? if so just change your join statement.

Comment: I'm  new in PS - can you give me an example of proper join statement?

Comment: "`n"  will inset a [newline] character "`r" will insert a [return] character if you are not sure which to use, you can get the current default by doing: $nl = [Environment]::NewLine

Comment: DOH! looks like i need to somehow escape that first character. It is a [tick] follewed by n or r. [tick] is the character in the far left top of a US keyboard. It looks kind of like a backwards apostrophe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know that ConvertTo-Html is cool, but if I want more control over generated HTML I do it manually:

```
$content = cat File.txt -Raw
$title = 'My HTML'
$html = @"
<html>
<head><title>$title</title></head>
<body>
<pre>$content</pre>
</body>
</html>
"@
$html | Out-File 'file.html'
```

`pre` tag is used in HTML to preserves preformatted element.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Stumbled into this answer 3.5 years later.  Your snippet worked perfectly for me doing something different, but related.  Bookmarked.  +1